# getting can't read property 'any' type error when we script in strict mode

Tags: javascript, this, strict-mode

while using `strict mode` I'm getting `type error` to access the `var` using `this`.

```js
"use strict";
var bar = "global";

function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}



var obj1 = {
    bar: "obj1",
    foo: foo
};

var obj2 = {
    bar: "obj2"
};

foo();

obj1.foo();
foo.call(obj2);
new foo();
```

**Screen shot:**

[image]

`foo();` is causing the problem. if I remove `"use strict"` everything is working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In strict mode, when you call a function without doing anything to set its `this`, `this` is `undefined`, not a reference to the global object. It's one of the big differences in strict mode. So if you want to call `foo` with a reference to the global object, you either:

1. At global scope, do `foo.call(this);` (since `this` at global scope is a reference to the global object), or
2. On browsers, do `foo.call(window);` (since `window` is a property on the global object it uses to point to itself -- other environments may also have other similar globals)

Here's an example of #1:

```js
"use strict";
var bar = "global";

function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}



var obj1 = {
    bar: "obj1",
    foo: foo
};

var obj2 = {
    bar: "obj2"
};

foo.call(this); // <=== changed

obj1.foo();
foo.call(obj2);
new foo();
```

...and of #2:

```js
"use strict";
var bar = "global";

function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}



var obj1 = {
    bar: "obj1",
    foo: foo
};

var obj2 = {
    bar: "obj2"
};

foo.call(window); // <=== changed

obj1.foo();
foo.call(obj2);
new foo();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}
```

'this' refers to the scope of the function foo.
you can either type bar in which the scope is implied to be window which is the global scope. or you can type window.bar.

```
function foo() {
   console.log(window.bar);
   console.log(bar);
}
```

Comment: *"'this' refers to the scope of the function foo"* No, it doesn't. Not at all.